# Keep track of external files

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive, file-management

what is the most elegant way of keeping track of your external data (archives)? I don't want to download a file which is already somewhere on my external USB drive. Right now, I use "dir /s >>list.txt" to create a directory listing dump as textfile on the main computer, but this is too cumbersome.
Perfect solution would be some kind of virtual drives which show the metadata for the external files; without having to actually connect the external source (USB-drive/stick).